# Can I reduce my jQuery code of many .on statements?

Tags: jquery

I am currently building a web application and I am basically building it using a lot of ajax requests, which require for me to use the `.on()` selector from jQuery to dynamically use elements. I have noticed though that my script is getting awfully long and it is very much the same code, but different functions to execute.

For example the code goes on like this:

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '.el01', function() {
        executeFunctionA($(this).data('x'));
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.el02', function() {
        showDivFunction();
        executeFunctionB(true);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.el03', function() {
        executeFunctionC($(this).data('x'), 300, false, function() {
            returnSomethingFromFunctionD();
        });
    });

    ............. Goes on for another 600 lines

});
```

I was wondering if there was a way to reduce all these `$(document).on()` statements? It would be stupid for me to continue like this if there was an easier way that reduces the amount of code. Maybe something like making `$(document).on('click')` a selector that I can call using `__c('el', f() {})` or something like that?

Comment: provide the code for all the related functions. i will shephard you to the light.

Comment: Basically it goes on like above.. I have 200 `.on('click')` events, each with a different DOM element as the trigger. Then theres a few `.on('mouseenter')` and `.on('submit')` events as well, but basically this question was more a wondering if it was possible to increase performance in some way, by reducing the amount of replicated code as shown above.

Comment: you can merge all of those functions including the click event into a single event that does different things based on the class of the clicked element. hence why i asked for more code. put up or shut up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you can't. [actually you can, but you shouldn't]

Long answer: You can only factor out **common** functionality. What you have is not common, since you use a different event handler for each class.

The most you can do is reduce the amount of typing you do by using a "map", eg:

```
var myEventHandlers = {
    '.el01': function() {
         executeFunctionA($(this).data('x'));
    },
    '.el02': function() {
        showDivFunction();
        executeFunctionB(true);
    },
    '.el03': function() {
        executeFunctionC($(this).data('x'), 300, false, function() {
            returnSomethingFromFunctionD();
        });
    }
};
```

And then add a single event handler, which delegates to the "mapping" object:

```
$(document).on('click', Object.keys(myEventHandlers).join(","), function(e) {
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    for(var i in classList) {
        myEventHandlers["." + i] && $.proxy(myEventHandlers["." + i], this, e);
    }
});
```

(The `for` loop  can be eliminated with an additional html attribute, e.g. `data-event-handler` if you have the option; or if you're guaranteed to only ever have one class per element)

---

This refactoring will save you one line per event handler (which, if you have 600 event hanlders, would be good), but it's not particularly *readable*, so if you do go with something along these lines make sure to *stick in a comment explaining why*

---

On second thought, what you asked about specifically would go like this:

```
function __c(selector, handler) {
    $(document).on('click', selector, handler);
}
__c('.el01', function(event) { /*...*/ });
```

However, this is both error-prone and very difficult to read. You should *not* do this just to save a couple of keystrokes -- as it gains you nothing else. The above approach at the very least makes it easy to see which handler goes with which class -- this way wouldn't.

Comment: Great thanks.. :) So I guess there's no point in doing it after all.. The code just seemed a bit inefficient, but I guess that I should stick to the way I am doing it now..

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to minimize your **on click** function. But someway or the other you must write your sub functions inside each **if** wrapper.

```
function ClkElmt(element) {
this.el = $(element);
this.check = function(){

  if (this.el.hasClass('el01')) {
      executeFunctionA($(this).data('x'));   
      console.log('el01'); 
  }

  if (this.el.hasClass('el02')) {
      showDivFunction();
      executeFunctionB(true);
      console.log('el02'); 
  }

  if (this.el.hasClass('el03')){       
      executeFunctionC($(this).data('x'), 300, false, function() {
      returnSomethingFromFunctionD();
      console.log('el03');
  }


 };
}


(function(){
   $('.el01, .el02, .el03, ....').on('click', function(){
   elemts = new ClkElmt(this);
   elemts.check();
  });
})();
```